# Error on Laravel Eloquent update function

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use laravel eloquent update method and I have this error Non-static method

> Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::update() should not be called statically

`View`

```html
@extends('posts.layout')

@section('content')
<form action="/posts/{{ $post->id }}" method="post">
    @method('PATCH')
    @csrf
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="{{ $post->title }}">
    <textarea name="body" placeholder="{{ $post->body }}"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Edit</button>
</form>
@endsection
```

`Controller Methods`

```php
public function edit(Post $post)
{
    return view('posts.edit', compact('post'));
}
public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
{
    post::update(request(['title', 'body']));
    return redirect('/posts');
}
```

Comment: Please show your code here as text, not as images.

Comment: Do you actually have a question or are you just showing us this error you made?

Comment: `post::update(...)` is not allowed (`::` is a static accessor, but `update()` is not a static function). If you have a `post $post`, you can just call `$post->update(...)`. Also, model names are `StudlyCase`, `post` should be `Post`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `$post` model object from the Dependency Injection to perform update on that object

```php
public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
{
  $post->title = $request->title;
  $post->body = $request->body;
  $post->save();
  return redirect('/posts');
}
```

Hope this helps